# Нестандартное оформление меню

Tags: css

Ребята, заинтересовало вот такое оформление меню. Не пойму, как встраивается нижний уголок в выбранном элементе как на [этом сайте](http://kreditka-onlain.ru/kredity-nalichnymi).

Comment: А Firebug/DevTools вы пользоваться не умеете?

Comment: Нет, а что это? Я на МК-61 программирую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь поточнее про какой ты уголок?

Comment: Ну в верхнем горизонтальном меню блок выделяется красным цветом, а нижний бордюр с внутренним треугольничком

Comment: Там просто добавляется картинка с активному пункту меню.

Comment: Иногда делают менюшку с косыми бордюрами - там тоже используются спрайты-картинки для background?

Comment: Нет,спрайты используют не всегда, однако применяются часто.
Ксс3 позволяет делать боковые ленты, треугольники без спрайтов, но картинками проще

Comment: http://kreditka-onlain.ru/wp-content/themes/kreditka-onlain/images/panel-select.png вот у них эта картинка просто добавляется к активному пункту в меню.

Comment: O_o, спасибо за уделенное мне внимание. Ответ засчитан!

Answer (score 2):

Лучше делать не, как на этом сайте, с помощью js, а с помощью css:

```
.active{
  position:relative;
}
.active:after{
  content:" ";  
  background-image:url('путь к картинке');  
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
}
```

Comment: да, согласен, как можно меньше скрипта - основное правило для веб-дизайна